# nftables ipv4 not loading

Tags: linux-kernel, ubuntu-18.04, nftables

I have a question about nftables in Ubuntu. I wanted to use nftables for a scientific application to send some image files from a remote telescope with UDP/IP from within a c++ telescope control program, and someone suggested that using nftables might be useful.
So I used the following commands to get nftables:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install nftables
```

following the installation guideline of the nftables wiki I loaded the module:

```
modprobe nf_tables
lsmode | grep nf_tables
nf_tables             143360  0
nfnetlink              16384  3 nf_conntrack_netlink,nf_tables
```

but I can not load the family modules:

```
modprobe nf_tables_ipv4
modprobe: FATAL: Module nf_tables_ipv4 not found in directory /lib/modules/5.4.0-70-generic
```

This is similar for nf_tables_ipv6.
I am running an Ubuntu 18.04 and Kernel 5.4.0.70. My question is that first how I should load the nf_tables_ipv4? Is it generally a problem when getting the distrbution packages and building from source solves it? or is there a different underlying issue that I can not load these family modules?

Second, are these essential packages necessary for my application?
And third: Given that I do not have any experience with it, is it actually a good idea to use nftables in my application? It is a very basic question, but I thought maybe someone can tell me if I am atleast on the right track here.

Thanks alot

Comment: The module may be built in to the kernel rather than loadable. On my Ubuntu 20.04 LTS with 5.4-0-71-generic kernel, `grep CONFIG_NF_TABLES_IPV4 /boot/config-$(uname -r)` outputs `CONFIG_NF_TABLES_IPV4=y`, indicating that it is built-in. (If it was a loadable module, the line would end with `=m`.)

Comment: oh thanks alot! I did not know that it could be built in. Thank you

Comment: Also, I thought the netfilter modules got auto-loaded on demand these days.